# Fill-paragraph respecting preview-latex

Tags: emacs

In Emacs I use preview-latex quite heavily for math equations. When I use fill-paragraph command to balance out the words in a paragraph however, I see that Emacs balances according to the LaTeX commands themselves, not images that represent the equations. For example I might have a long command that looks like $\bar{\theta_1},\bar{\theta_2}$ that translate into two characters on the screen. If these commands appear near the middle of a line, fill-paragraph would cut off the line and move the rest to the next, which makes the cut-off line look very short. Is there any way to change this so that fill-paragraph and preview-latex work well together?

[image]
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I also experience this with `org-mode`'s LaTeX overlays. I think the challenge is that the overlays aren't really part of the buffer content, so you'd be wrapping each line to a different text column. Upvoted, because I'd be interested in seeing a solution.

Comment: Similar talk here but no solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/mhEe90Xc-Fg